# Change view in one XIB

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to make an app using `Interface Builder` (instead of `Storyboard`) for the first time, but I'm stuck. Is it possible to change view using a `ViewController` in the same `XIB`?
I'd like that when I tap a button, the view changes to the other `ViewController` present in the same `XIB file`. Must I call back an action? If yes, which?

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to do, is what storyboards were made for. Why do you want to use a xib file? I think that Apple's intention was that storyboards should largely replace xib files as the new way to make the user interface.

Comment: You're right, in fact I usually use storyboards; but I wanted to try Interface Builder at this time. The problem is that I've almost finished my app, I cannot restart for this little problem.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do -- xib files contain views, not view controllers (the view controller is usually the File's owner). You can put multiple views in the xib file if you want, and switch between them for your one controller, but that doesn't switch view controllers.

Comment: In fact in the comment below I corrected; I have two windows, not two ViewControllers in my .xib file. Sorry for the mistake, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2 view controllers with 2 .xib files, like this

[image]

*You can present the NextViewControler from your ViewController's button press method,*

```
-(IBAction) yourButtonPressed:(id)sender;{
    NextViewController *nextViewController = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:nextViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**EDIT :**

You can present the same viewcontroller like this.

```
-(IBAction) yourButtonPressed:(id)sender;{
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: No, I have only 1 .xib file with one ViewController.

Comment: Thank you, but I made a mistake; I have two windows, not two ViewControllers. So I used the "AppDelegate" for the first window. The button should change the view from the first window to the second when is pressed. Sorry!

Comment: Use only one window and 2 ViewControllers.